# Is this java class thread safe? Concurrent read and write

Tags: java, concurrency

Is the following class thread safe? I am worrying about concurrent read and write the initialized variable. If it is not thread safe, how to make it thread safe?

1. I know convert methodA to synchronized will help, but I don't want to do this
2. How about add volatile keywork to "initialized" variable?

```
public class A {

    private boolean initialized;

    public synchronized void init(String configFilePath) {
        if (initialized) {
            return;
        }

        initialized = true;
    }

    public void methodA() {
        if (!initialized) {
            throw new ConfigurationException()
        }
    }
}
```

Update1:
The initialized variable will only be modified once in init method, all other methods will only ready. If that is the case, adding volatile to initialized will make it thread safe, is that correct?

Comment: The class is definitely not thread-safe, and making your `initialized` variable `volatile` is not going to make it thread-safe. The question is, can you live with it? If your program indeed throws an exception when `initialized` is `false` and does not do anything else, then the answer is probably "yes, after making `initialized` variable `volatile`".

Comment: It's really meaningless to ask if these methods are "safe" out of context of their use.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, Yes, the methodA will throw exception. If initialized is volatile, I think it should be thread safe

Comment: @performanceuser I think the question is: is it ok for methodA to throw an exception if init is already running but not complete yet? If it is ok, then volatile is all you need. If not then you need to describe what you expect methodA to do when init has started but not finished yet.

Comment: @performanceuser It wouldn't be thread-safe, but the consequences are going to be so mild that you can safely ignore this fact.

Comment: @assylias, Very good point. Yes, methodA needs to throw exception if init has started but not finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not thread safe. The `init` routine could be in the middle of setting `initialized` when `methodA` is called. Since `methodA` is not synchronized, there's nothing preventing a race between executing `initialized = true` and the read in `if( !initialized)`. In fact, the write could even have happened but simply not yet propagated to the thread that called `methodA`

Adding `volatile` to `initialized` would help with the value propagation problem, but not with the first.

For more info on this, I recommend Brian Goetz's article [Managing Volatility](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/index.html).

Comment: If I add volatile to initialized, why it is till not thread safe? Can you explain?

Comment: @performanceuser - If all that `init()` does with `initialized` is test it at the beginning and then write to it at the end, then the method itself doesn't need to be synchronized and you can get by with `volatile`. (If `init()` itself might be called from several threads, then it still needs to be synchronized.) The exact factors that go into this analysis are described very well in the Goetz article I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

No its not thread safe. 
you have to syncronize.

Answer (score 0):

@HotLicks is 100% correct. Any question regarding concurrency needs to provide context. Here's why:

Let's assume a class has been written to be "safe" (ignoring the OPs class for the moment). If you are synchronizing on an instance variable and the instance of the class is shared by many threads, then it will be thread-safe. However, if multiple instances of the class can be created (by the different threads), and they potentially modify static variables/state, then it will only be thread-safe if you synchronize on a static (i.e. class) variable.

**In summary:**

1. If sharing single instance between threads, then lock on instance variable
2. If threads are creating instances of the "safe" class AND static state is potentially modified by those threads, then must lock on static (class) variable